# awk: Preventing result being interpreted as shell command

Tags: date, awk

I have some pairs of dates like the following

```
2012-11-23T09:26:20 2012-11-23T09:26:48 
2012-11-23T09:26:48 2012-11-23T09:26:48 
2012-11-23T09:26:26 2012-11-23T10:49:38 
2012-11-23T10:49:38 2012-11-23T10:49:38 
2012-11-23T09:26:30 2012-11-23T12:17:13 
2012-11-23T12:17:13 2012-11-23T12:17:13 
2012-11-23T09:26:33 2012-11-23T13:39:52 
2012-11-23T13:39:52 2012-11-23T13:39:52
```

I want to find the difference between the two date for each line.  So far I have

```
awk '{cmd="$(( ( $(date -ud \""$2"\" +\"%s\") - $(date -ud \""$1"\" +\"%s\") ) ))"; cmd | getline diff; print diff }' < submit_start.txt
```

which produces

```
sh: 28: command not found

sh: 0: command not found

sh: 4992: command not found

sh: 0: command not found

sh: 10243: command not found

sh: 0: command not found

sh: 15199: command not found

sh: 0: command not found
```

I seem to get the result interpreted as a shell command and printing 'diff' just
seems to add a newline.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: ++  for pluck, but you know  you can do this without awk, right?  `while read dt1 dt2 ; do echo $(( date $dt1 .... date $dt2 ....) ; done < submit_start.txt`. Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing an `echo` in your command:

```
awk '{cmd="echo $(( ( $(date -ud \""$2"\" +\"%s\") - $(date -ud \""$1"\" +\"%s\") ) ))"; cmd | getline diff; print diff }' file
```

Without the `echo`, you are attempting to execute each of the results as a command. I also removed the `<` from the line as it isn't necessary.

As [Ed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton) has mentioned in the comments, there are a few things to watch out for when using `getline`. You should test that it has succeeded and also close `cmd` when you're done:

```
awk '{cmd="echo $(( ( $(date -ud \""$2"\" +\"%s\") - $(date -ud \""$1"\" +\"%s\") ) ))"; diff = ( (cmd | getline line) > 0 ? line : -1 ); close(cmd); print diff }' file
```

Alternatively, there's no harm in using the shell for this task, as almost all of the work is being done outside of awk:

```
while read -r dt1 dt2; do
    echo "$(( $(date -ud "$dt2" +%s) - $(date -ud "$dt1" +%s) ))"
done < file
```

Comment: Don't forget to test the result of the getline and close the cmd afterwards, i.e. `cmd | getline diff` should be something more like `diff = ( (cmd | getline line) > 0 ? line : -1 ); close(cmd)`. See http://awk.info/?tip/getline for how/when to use getline.

Answer (score 1):

Use GNU awk for time functions:

```
$ gawk '{print secs($2) - secs($1)} function secs(t){gsub(/[^0-9]/," ",t); return mktime(t)}' file   
28
0
4992
0
10243
0
15199
0
```